# `gcloud docker` command refreshing access token on each invocation

Tags: gcloud

**macOS**

```
Google Cloud SDK 183.0.0
beta 2017.09.15
bq 2.0.27
core 2017.12.08
gcloud
gsutil 4.28
kubectl
```

I have tried revoking the login and logging in again but every command of `gcloud docker` refreshes the access token so it hangs about 30 seconds before actually executing a command.

```
$ gcloud --verbosity=debug docker -- --help                                                                                                                                                      
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.docker] with arguments: [--verbosity: "debug"]
INFO: Refreshing access_token

$ gcloud --verbosity=debug docker -- --help                                                                                                                                                          
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.docker] with arguments: [--verbosity: "debug"]
INFO: Refreshing access_token
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

#### Login Debug Log

```
$ gcloud --verbosity=debug auth login                                                                        
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.auth.login] with arguments: [--verbosity: "debug"]
Your browser has been opened to visit:

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8085%2F&prompt=select_account&response_type=code&client_id=32555940559.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fappengine.admin+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcompute+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Faccounts.reauth&access_type=offline


INFO: Successfully retrieved access token
WARNING: `gcloud auth login` no longer writes application default credentials.
If you need to use ADC, see:
  gcloud auth application-default --help

You are now logged in as [xxx].
Your current project is [xxx].  You can change this setting by running:
  $ gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID
INFO: Display format "none".
```

Comment: Can you paste the DEBUG-level output of your login command? (Remove any personal information of course.)

Comment: @RodneyJonace Thanks for taking a look. I've added the log--it's not much info though

Comment: @RodneyJonace Any other suggestions?

Comment: We've had similar problems and worked around them by running `gcloud docker -a` to get the token once. Subsequently, you can use the normal docker command to execute any commands you are interested in.